# How would I use a data-attribute in HTML to fill a link and image source with a link from a database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a database that has a table with a column called "link" that holds a link such as this "http://www.google.com", and a column called "image" that holds this "http://www.placehold.it/500x500".

I then have the following html:

```
<a href="" data-field="link">
  <img src="" data-field="image">
</a>
```

I have a PHP backend that uses JSON and a JQuery plugin to retrieve and populate information but I don't know how to fill the href"" and src"" attributes specifically.

How can I do this with JQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Can include returned `json` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the the thing you want?

```
$("a[data-field='link']").attr("href",yourValue);
$("img[data-field='image']").attr("src",yourAnotherValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/0jLad8hj/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').attr('href', function(){
    return $(this).data('field');
}).find('img').attr('src', function(){
        return $(this).data('field');
    });;
});
```

Use the .attr function from jQuery. The first value is the attribute to set and the second is the value. .data gets the data-attribute